# window object, closure, or the 'this' in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, openlayers

In the process of developing an OpenLayers map application using Vue, which is the most sensible way to manage the mapContainer?

I tried using a closure to address this issue, but the outcome doesn't seem to be what I expected. I thought there would only be one memory leak, but in reality, there is a memory leak every time it's called.
For instance, in removing a layer, I tried to retain the map object using a closure.

```
/**
 * remove the layer
 * @param {ol.Map} map ol map container
 *  @param {Number} index the index of the layer to be removed
 */
export function removeVectorLayer(map) {
  return function (index) {
    const removeLayer = map.getLayers().getArray()[index + 4];
    map.removeLayer(removeLayer);
    this.$store.commit("spliceMapList", [index, 1]);
  };
}
```

Then execute it in Vue.

```
this.removeVectorLayer = removeVectorLayer(map, this.$store.state.mapList);
```

Comment: what if you `return (index) =>` instead?

Comment: As @JaromandaX suggests, use an arrow function if you want to persist `this` in a closure.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but my intention was not to use 'this' correctly in the local function. I was trying to preserve the map variable in this way.